# How to get each cell's position

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uiviewanimation

I need to know where exactly each cell in a tableView is at while scrolling.

Tried this but it just returns null.. probably does not make sense.

```
self.cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (self.cell == nil) {
    self.cell = [[Cell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    NSNumber *cellOriginY = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:self.cell.frame.origin.y];

    [self.cellPositionArray addObject:cellOriginY];
}
```

I first tried to manage this function I'm trying to add with indexPath like this :

```
CGRect visibleRect = (CGRect){.origin = self.tableView.contentOffset, .size = self.view.bounds.size};
CGPoint visiblePoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(visibleRect), CGRectGetMidY(visibleRect));
NSIndexPath *visibleIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:visiblePoint];
```

Which kind of works but then later I found out multiple cells with same indexPath get selected. I guess it's because indexPath is not unique so that leaves me with no other choices than managing it with each cell's Y axis.
Any other idea..?

Comment: What's the point of this exercise? Even if you could get the origin there, every single origin in the `cellPositionArray` would be off as soon as the end-user touches the screen with his little finger.

Comment: So I can match its indexPath and its Y axis to find out which one is which because indexPath gives me a several cells with same indexPath here and there.

Comment: It still isn't clear what you are trying to achieve.  Why do you need to know the cell's location?

Comment: It's a slide out menu that comes out from the left each time a cell shows up on screen.(Only one cell is entirely shown so one cell shows up, the menu comes out. The cell either goes up or down, its menu hides and the next shows up.. and the menu's height is the same as its cell's) I've made it work then later realized multiple cells' menus would come out at the same time not just the one I select because they have same indexPath. I need to filter which one is which.

Comment: Can you use the `visibleCells` property of the tableview in conjunction with the `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate method of the tableview?  I don't know what you mean by index paths are not unique.

Comment: When I call indexPath in a label to see each cell's indexPath, they're not all unique. Some rows have the same indexPath.. But now that I check indexPath.row by tapped point (specific row when tapped), I do get different row number each time. Not sure why but it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out with the code I already had. 
It's probably not a good way to do this but.. for now!

```
CGRect visibleRect = (CGRect){.origin = self.tableView.contentOffset, .size = self.view.bounds.size};
CGPoint zeroPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(visibleRect), CGRectGetMinY(visibleRect));
```

And each time you scroll, check -

```
if (zeroPoint.y == (int)visibleIndexPath.row * 380)
```

380 is the height of each cell.
Although, it only works when you scroll slowly so you'd have to enhance the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

When I want to try and see how my cells are formatting themselves I'll often call in a label to put on my cell that displays the information I need from it. I'm assuming you are using a custom `UITableView` class and that is why you call `self.cell` instead of creating and returning a cell as you would do in the required `UITableViewDataSourceProtocol`'s. You don't have your functions header so I can't really tell, but use this protocol and make sure you have self.delegate = self. That should display each cell with the info you are looking for. If you don't have a grouped tableView then section would just display 0 everytime. Each IndexPath has two values, section and row.

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(UITableView *)tableView forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        if(self.cell == nil) {
               UILabel *label = [UILabel new];
               label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %ld in section %ld starting at point %f", indexPath.row, indexPath.section, self.cell.fram.origin.y ];
               [self.cell addSubView:label]; //Forgot to add this to first post.

               //New Code For CustomViews
               CustomView *customView = [self.customViews objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
               [self.cell addSubView:customView];
               }
        }
```

Hope you can use this to find what you are looking for. Try adding more info about the class you are doing this in such as header file if you have more questions.
//Answer to your other question:
Best way I can think of to work through a simple tableView is using an NSArray. Simplest way is to add an array property to the tableView class.

`@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) NSMutableArray *customViews;`

then in your 'ViewController.m' in 'ViewDidLoad' initialize your array and items in it after initializing the custom table view class.

```
'customTableView.customImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: cutomView1, customView2, etc..., nil];'
```

After you have that its simple I'll add code in my previous answer to how u set the views to the cell. It will make it so row 0 will have the objectAtIndex[0], row 1 objectAtIndex[1] etc.

Make sure to update your `numberOfRowsInSection` protocol method with 
`return [self.customImages count]'
so that your table view doesn't create more cells than it needs.

Comment: Ok thank you so much! Yes there's custom cell class, I do have all the delegates and everything. Not grouped, the section does always display 0 yes. I've been looking at section and row this whole time and just was't paying enough attention.. row numbers return 0,1,2,3.. so yeah I can now distinguish each cell by row number I see. But how do I add items in a certain row? I'm doing this to add the view I want each time user scrolls. self.optionViewCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:visibleIndexPath]; This still adds the same view to multiple rows with the same whatever it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if `cell.contentView` doesn't work, might be use any control on `cell.contentView`.

```
CGPoint point = [cell.contentView.superview convertPoint:cell.contentView.frame.origin toView:nil];
```